# Limitar número digitado

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Eu tenho um campo number onde preciso que seja digitado um valor de 0 a 25, caso o usuário digite um número acima de 25 ele não permita, tentei usar o **max="25"** mas ele só bloqueie caso a pessoa não digite, tem algum jeito de fazer isso em jquery?

```html
<input type="number" min="1" max="25"  class="form-control" name="qtdbuffet7">
```

Comment: Da uma olhada no link, acho que pode te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761852/maximum-and-minimum-values-in-a-textbox

Comment: Uma dica que eu daria é não usar o `type` `number`, se você espera ter usuários do Safari na sua aplicação

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode fazer diretamente no evento `onchange` do campo. No exemplo abaixo o valor será alterado para os limites caso sejam ultrapassados:

```html
<input type="number"
       min="1"
       max="25"
       class="form-control"
       name="qtdbuffet7"
       onkeyup="this.value = this.value > 25 ? 25 : this.value < 0 ? 0 : this.value"
>
```

Comment: Entendi, não sabia que dava para usar o onchange para isso, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Sorack, eu estou conseguindo digitar o número 26 por exemplo, ou o 266, ou o 354353. Mas como está correto(pelo autor da pergunta) eu não devo ter entendido a pergunta então...

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti quando você sai do campo o valor é corrigido

Comment: Tinha editado sua resposta mas desfiz a edição... não seria melhor aplicar o `onkeyup`? Porque o problema dele era com o  teclado

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti então, tem que dar uma testada pra ver se não vamos ter comportamentos anômalos quando a digitação for muito rápida

Comment: Não tem, fica melhor pois a validação é "on demand" e não só depois do usuário sair do input

Answer (score 0):

Ele também bloqueia quando você digita em um campo utilizando o atributo `max`, porém a ação de bloqueio só é validado quando você estiver chamando a ação de *submit* em seu formulário, se o valor esteja acima do valor limite `max`, será exibido um alerta semelhante a seguir:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Exemplo stackoverflow.com</h2>

<form action="/minha_pagina.php">
    <input type="number" name="number" min="0" max="25"><br><br>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit"> 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora, se você quizer fazer essa validação no momento do preenchimento do formulário, você pode usar a função `onkeyup` e adaptar para como você deseja que funcione, ou seguir o exemplo do [@Sorack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/59479/sorack) utilizando a função `onchange`.

Comment: Jovem, nem fui eu que negativei, **mas deixar que o usuário erre o que digitou, para só depois corrigi-lo é um anti patter de eurística**, um erro desse tipo pode facilmente irritar o usuário, ou mesmo fazer com que ele abandone o preenchimento ou finalize a compra... Não acredito que essa seja uma boa prática. Além do mais esse "alert"vai de cada Browser e esse comportamento pode fugir ao controle  do dev. e do designer.

Comment: Agradeço o feedback e concordo com você @hugocsl, inclusive quando se trata na possibilidade **de permitir que o usuário erre o que digitou**, porém, esse não é o caso que usei como critérios para realizar essa resposta. O autor da pergunta *mencionou* que essa propriedade **não bloqueia caso o usuário não digite**, e a minha intenção era apenas explanar que isso é possível, trazendo juntamente um modelo exemplo.

Comment: Entendi seu ponto de vista, foi mais uma dica do que crítica...
Não indico que faça isso em algum projeto seu no futuro ;)

Comment: Aceito todas as críticas e dicas, sendo positivas ou não. Agradeço mais uma vez por ter vindo opinar ao invés de apenas dar um *downvote*, como muitos fazem. Acontece que eu explanei como citei no comentário acima a minha resposta foi baseada em uma afirmação do autor que achei incorreta.